# Returning generic type from cypher query

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm creating an asp.net web api.  Many of the routes all do the same thing, just with different node objects.  I'd like to create a base model from a BaseRepository class and simply have the child class cast and return the object(s).

For example.  GET api/{controller}
The only thing that changes in this cypher query is the Label of the node which is easily provided as a parameter.

I've tried many, many ways to do this such as.

```
var query = client
            .Cypher
            .Match(string.Format("(node:{0})", label))
            .Return(node => node.As<Node<object.GetType()>>())
            .Limit(10)
            .Results;
```

But the lambda will not accept that.  I've tried

```
.Return(node => node.As<Node<string>>())
```

and converting it to the object type and dynamic but it says I can't do that either.

Is there anyway to do what I'm trying here or maybe another avenue could be suggested so that I don't have to write dozens of GET api/{controller} methods exactly the same way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken a similar approach in some solutions by using generics. Do your types match your labels? If so I wonder if this approach can go some way to solving your issue?

```
public T GetNode<T>(Guid nodeId)
{
    // derive the label from the type name
    var label = typeof(T).Name;
    // now build the query
    var query = client.Cypher
        .Match(string.Concat("(node:", label, " { nodeid : {nodeid} })"))
        .WithParams(new { nodeid = nodeId })
        .Return(node => node.As<T>())
        .Limit(10)
        .Results;

    // now do something with the results
}
```

Obviously this is using a schema index to search for a specific node but you could omit that part, e.g.

```
    // derive the label from the type name
    var label = typeof(T).Name;
    // now build the query
    var query = client.Cypher
        .Match(string.Concat("(node:", label, ")"))
        .Return(node => node.As<T>())
        .Limit(10)
        .Results;

    // now do something with the results
```

Any mileage in this?

Comment: You are spot on man(or woman), that worked perfectly!  I can't thank you enough!